# TestNG: Is it possible to use DataProvider in AfterTest(), AfterClass(), AfterMethod()?

Tags: java, testng, rest-assured, testng-dataprovider

I am writing few test in which I am using DataProvider for @Test and creating few thing now as a cleanup/teardown() step I want to delete these things in @After methods, how can I use DataProvider in AfterTest(), AfterClass(), AfterMethod() ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. For example TestNg can inject the same objects to `@AfterMethod`. See the example below:

```java
@DataProvider(name = "test")
public Object[][] testDataProvide(){
    return new Object[][]{
            {"11", "12"},
            {"21", "22"}
    };
}

@Test(dataProvider = "test")
public void testDP(String one, String two){
    System.out.println(String.join(",", one, two));
}

@AfterMethod
public void tearDownEach(Object[] args){
    System.out.println("Tearing down: " + String.join(",", args[0].toString(), args[1].toString()));
}
```

**P.S.** -  `AfterTest()` and `AfterClass()` do not have such way since they run after a bunch of tests have completed which does not make sense to use with data provider that is intended to supply a **piece** of data to every **single** test.

Comment: I tried `AfterMethod` as you suggested but I am getting this error : `org.testng.TestNGException: 
Can inject only one of <ITestContext, XmlTest, Method, Object[], ITestResult> into a @AfterMethod annotated deleteAndValidate.
`

Comment: `@DataProvider(name = "body")
    public Object[] body() throws IOException{
        JsonArray jArray = HelperMethods.ReadJsonFileReturnJsonArray(filePath);
        Object[] data = new Object[jArray.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i<jArray.size(); i++){
            data[i] = jArray.get(i);
        }
        return data;
    } @AfterMethod
    public void deleteAndValidate(Object arrays) throws Exception {
        String body = arrays.toString();
        System.out.println(body);
    }`

Comment: 1 - Data provider has to return `Object[][]`, not just `Object[]`. 2 - AfterMethod has to take `Object[]`, not just `Object`. Please carefully check my example and adopt it to your case.